# ninject factory constructor selection with runtime generics

Tags: constructor, arguments, ninject, factory

How can I use a ninject factory, which creates an instance with constructor parameters, without relying on the argument names.

The problem is that the `ToConstructor()`-Method not works, because I bind it to a generic definition.

The following example works, if I use the factory method with the corresponding constructor argument name, but I don't like it rely on names.

Because the following solution is very fragil and breaks if someone chooses a wrong name or renames the ctor-argument in the derived class.

Any solution?

Here's the example code:

```
[TestFixture]
public class NinjectFactoryBindingsTest
{
    [Test]
    public void ConstructorSelectionWithArguments()
    {
        NinjectSettings ninjectSettings = new NinjectSettings();
        ninjectSettings.LoadExtensions = false;

        using (var kernel = new StandardKernel(ninjectSettings, new FuncModule()))
        {
            // IDependencyA will be passed to the factory, therefore it is not bounded
            //kernel.Bind<IDependencyA>().To<DependencyA>();
            kernel.Bind<IDependencyB>().To<DependencyB>();

            kernel.Bind(typeof(IGenericBaseClass<>)).To(typeof(GenericDerivedClass<>));
            kernel.Bind<IGenericClassFactory>().ToFactory();

            IGenericClassFactory factory = kernel.Get<IGenericClassFactory>();

            DependencyA dependencyA = new DependencyA();

            IGenericBaseClass<GenericImpl> shouldWorkInstance = factory.Create<GenericImpl>(dependencyA);

            Assert.NotNull(shouldWorkInstance);

        }
    }
}    

public interface IGenericClassFactory
{
    IGenericBaseClass<TGeneric> Create<TGeneric>(IDependencyA someName) where TGeneric : IGeneric;
    // This works, but relies on ctor-param-names!!!
    // IGenericBaseClass<TGeneric> Create<TGeneric>(IDependencyA otherNameThanInBaseClass) where TGeneric : IGeneric; 
}

public class DependencyA : IDependencyA
{
}

public class DependencyB : IDependencyB
{
}

public class GenericDerivedClass<TGeneric> : GenericBaseClass<TGeneric> where TGeneric : IGeneric
{
    public GenericDerivedClass(IDependencyA otherNameThanInBaseClass, IDependencyB dependencyB)
        : base(otherNameThanInBaseClass, dependencyB)
    {
    }
}

public abstract class GenericBaseClass<TGeneric> : IGenericBaseClass<TGeneric> where TGeneric : IGeneric
{
    protected GenericBaseClass(IDependencyA dependencyA, IDependencyB dependencyB)
    {
    }
}

public interface IGenericBaseClass<TGeneric> where TGeneric : IGeneric
{
}

public interface IDependencyB
{
}

public interface IDependencyA
{
}

public class GenericImpl : IGeneric
{
}

public interface IGeneric
{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The factory extension has the convention that arguments must have the same name as the constructor argument they will be passed to. There are no easy ways to do it differently. The only way I can think of is about the following:

1. Create a new IParameter implementation that can hold a reference to an IDependencyA.
2. Create either a hardcoded factory or a custom IInstanceProvider (see documentation) that creates an instance of your IParameter implementation so that it is passed to the Get<> request
3. Add a new binding for IDependencyA: `Bind<IDependency>().ToMethod(ctx => extract and return your parameter from the context)`

Comment: Thx Remo for the idea. I've created new Parameter that implements `IConstructorArgument`. Now it's easy to check with `bool AppliesToTarget(...)`.